# xslt: 2-argument function not recognized

Tags: xml, function, xslt

In the following XSLT snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:my="bla">

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="my:add(4,2)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="my:add" as="xs:integer">
        <xs:param name="n" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:param name="k" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$n + $k"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following errors:

```
Static error in {my:add(4,2)} in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 9 column 40 of john.xsl:
  XPST0017: Cannot find a 2-argument function named {bla}add(). The namespace URI and local
  name are recognized, but the number of arguments is wrong
Static error at char 3 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 30 column 37 of john.xsl:
  XPST0008: Variable n has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

I know I could use `<xsl:function name="my:add" as="xs:integer*">` as the function head but I do not want to have it this way. I can not find out what is wrong with this because I found several similar examples like this.

Comment: You need to do `xsl:param` not `xs:param` in the function....

Comment: Note that in most cases, to return a function result of a certain type an XPath expression computes (e.g. in your `$n + $k`) the right way is to use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of` (e.g. in your case `<xsl:sequence select="$n + $k"/>`), as `xsl:value-of` creates a text node with the string representation the the values of the sequence computed in the `select` attribute while `xsl:sequence` simply returns the selected/computed sequence.

Comment: So while the `as="xs:integer"` on your function declaration would ensure the text node you create with `xsl:value-of` is converted to an integer as the function result the "natural" way to return the integer computed by `$n + $k` is to use `xsl:sequence` and not to use `xsl:value-of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function parameters are in the Schema namespace. They need to be in the XSLT namespace.

Without any [`xsl:param`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-param), it is a zero arity function that contains two param elements that are in the Schema namespace.

> [Definition: The **arity** of a stylesheet function is the number of xsl:param elements in the function definition.] Optional arguments are not allowed.

Change the namespace prefix from `xs` to `xsl` on your `param` elements: `xsl:param`.

Also, since your function is returning an integer, use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:value-of`. `xsl:value-of` will produce a string from the numeric result, which will then need to be cast to an `xs:integer`. Just return the numeric product as-is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:my="bla">

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:value-of select="my:add(4,2)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="my:add" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="n" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:param name="k" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$n + $k"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```